# Scraping table with PHP Simple HTML DOM PARSER

Tags: php, web-scraping, html-table

I would like to scrape a pretty big table and only extract title and date from it. I adapted an example file and it gives me just what I want but only for the first table entry

```
<?php
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_table() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.example.org');

    // get table
    foreach($html->find('table[id=example]') as $article) {
        // get title
        $item['title'] = trim($article->find('td.title', 0)->plaintext);
        // get date
        $item['date'] = trim($article->find('td.date', 0)->plaintext);

        $ret[] = $item;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!
$ret = scraping_table();

foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo '<h3>'.$v['title'].'</h3>';
    echo '<p>'.$v['date'].'</p>';
}

?>
```

Removing ", 0" of course doesn't do the job...I'm a total PHP noob and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$html->find('table[id=example]')` will only find one result (if the html is valid) so your loop on runs once. Probably you want to loop over the table rows

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was missing.